# Drawing squares and drawing circles with radio buttons not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, radio-button

My question today is to ask why when i switch radio buttons, drawing a circle doesn't work. Im creating a paint program. Please help me with this question.

Html:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="200"></canvas>

<h2>Choose your drawing shape:</h2>
<p>
  <input type="radio" name="shape" onclick="square=true;" checked="checked">Square
  <input type="radio" name="shape" onclick="square=false;">Circle
</p>

<h2>Color Settings:</h2>

<input type="color" id="myColor" />

<form id="colorForm">
  <h3>Basic Colours:</h3>
  <p>
    <input type="radio" name="color" value="black" checked="checked" />Black
    <input type="radio" name="color" value="red" />Red
    <input type="radio" name="color" value="orange" />Orange
    <input type="radio" name="color" value="yellow" />Yellow
    <input type="radio" name="color" value="green" />Green
    <input type="radio" name="color" value="blue" />Blue
    <input type="radio" name="color" value="purple" />Purple
    <input type="radio" name="color" value="white" />Eraser (White)
  </p>
</form>


<form id="sizeForm">
  <h2>Size:</h2>
  <p>
    <input type="radio" name="size" value="10" />Big
    <input type="radio" name="size" value="5" checked="checked" />Normal
    <input type="radio" name="size" value="2" />Small
  </p>
</form>
      <button onclick="clearCanvas()">Clear Drawing</button>
```

Css:

```
#canvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
  cursor: crosshair;
}
h2,
h3 {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
h2 {
  font-size: 1.1rem;
}
h3 {
  font-size: 1rem;
}
```

And javascript:

```
var square = true; // Set

var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var size = 5
var eraserSize = 5;

$('#colorForm input, #myColor').on('change', function() {
  ctx.fillStyle = $(this).val();
});

$('#sizeForm input').on('change', function() {
  size = $(this).val();
});


var drawRect = function (event) {
  var posX = event.pageX - $(canvas).offset().left - 4
  var posY = event.pageY - $(canvas).offset().top - 4
  ctx.fillRect(posX, posY, size, size)
}

 var drawCircle = function (event) {
  var posX = event.pageX - $(canvas).offset().left
  var posY = event.pageY - $(canvas).offset().top
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(posX, posY, size - 1, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.fill();
}

function mouseDown(e) {
  // We only care about mousemove on the canvas, not the whole page
  if (square) {
    $(canvas).on('mousemove', drawRect).on('mouseup', drawRect);
  } else {
    $(canvas).on('mousemove', drawCircle).on('mouseup', drawCircle);
  }

  // If the user mouseup outside of the canvas, we don't want to keep listening, so listen for mouseup on the whole page to remove our other drawing listeners
  $('html').one('mouseup', function() { // "one" means that it will only fire once and will stop listening after that (cleanup for free)
    $(canvas).off('mousemove').off('mouseup');
  });
}

function clearCanvas() {
  if (confirm("Are you sure you want to clear your drawing?") == true) {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 300, 300)
  }
}

// We only care about mousedown on the canvas, not the whole page
$(canvas).on('mousedown', mouseDown);
```

Please help me with this question. Thanks for your support!!!

Comment: What do you mean draw circle not work, it seems working to me: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9aktLhkd/).

Comment: Oh yeah whoops, i got my settings wrong probably so that's not why it's working. Thx for you help m8!